# How to get basic html in chrome web view input text to scaling like other text elements or bad chrome user agent?

Tags: html, css

Working on a bare bones html page - and noticed in the web view that input boxes and associated labels are not scaling to the view like other text elements, odd behaviour?

Web view being physical phone (pixel 2) and desktop chrome mobile emulation.
Bot showing the input box much smaller, actully its scaling all the other elements, mostly text (dl/spans) from 16px to 29.3px

Only css added is setting font-family, and disabling this has not difference.

When copied a label and placed else where on page, it scales.

Default chrome (as far as I know, unless plug-in causing issues)
Chromes user agent does have a lot of css on the input. Is this just bad chrome default css, or something missing maybe in the meta to help alleviate this issue

Inputs near the top of this image. Left is Emulated web view, but get same issue on hardware device. Right side is normal desktop view.

Chrome browser.
FireFox does not appear to demonstrate this behaviour.
Attempted running in JSFiddle and could not get it to show the same issue.

[image]

```html
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>My Comics</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace
        }
    </style>
</head>

<!-- next task:  On edit - fill with that issues details -->

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Menu item</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <h1>My Comics JSON</h1>
    <input type="file" accept=".json" id="global-load">

    <label for="search-series">Series</label>
    <input type="text" id="search-series" class="search-input" data-search="Series">
    <label for="search-issue">Issue</label>
    <input type="text" id="search-issue" class="search-input" data-search="IssueID">
    <label for="search-issue">All</label>
    <input type="text" id="search-depth" class="search-input" data-search="Depth">
    <i id="search-state" style="display: none;">searching...</i>

    <div id="stats">
        <label>Series</label><h1>View Stats</h1>
        <dl>
            <dt>Series</dt><dd class="stat-info Series">0</dd>
            <dt>Have</dt><dd class="stat-info Have">8</dd>
            <dt>Issues</dt><dd class="stat-info Issues">8</dd>
            <dt>Duplicates</dt><dd class="stat-info Dups">0</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>

    <div id="main-body">
            <section>
                <h1 class="Name">X-23 vol. 3 (2018)</h1>
                <ul class="Issues">
                
            <li>
                <input class="Have" title="I have" type="checkbox"> 
                #<span class="IssueID">1</span> 
                <span class="CoverDate" data-format="[$]">[___ 2018]</span>
                <span class="Title"></span> 
                <span class="Type"></span> 
                <span class="Collection"></span>  
                <span class="Paid">£4.20</span>  
                <span class="Where">Travelling Man, Manchester</span>  
                <span class="When">2018-08-11</span>  
                <!-- <span class="Purchase"></span> <button class='edit'>edit</button> -->
            </li>
        
            <li>
                <input class="Have" title="I have" type="checkbox"> 
                #<span class="IssueID">2</span> 
                <span class="CoverDate" data-format="[$]">[___ 2018]</span>
                <span class="Title"></span> 
                <span class="Type"></span> 
                <span class="Collection"></span>  
                <span class="Paid">£3.30</span>  
                <span class="Where">Forbidden Planet International, Manchester</span>  
                <span class="When">2018-09-15</span>  
                <!-- <span class="Purchase"></span> <button class='edit'>edit</button> -->
            </li>
        
            
        
            
        
            
        
            
        
            
        
            
        </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
    
    <div id="series-view">
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="item-view">
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="series-edit">
    
    </div>
    
    <!--
    <div id="item-edit">
        <form class="edit">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="text" class="key" value="IssueID" readonly><input type="number" class="value"></li>
                <li><label><input class="Have" data-Property="Have" title="I have" type="checkbox" /> Have</label></li>
                <li><input type="text" class="key" value="Paid"><input type="text" class="value"></li>
                <li><input type="text" class="key" value="Where"><input type="text" class="value"></li>
                <li><input type="text" class="key" value="When"><input type="text" class="value"></li>
                <li><input type="text" class="key" ><input type="text" class="value"></li>
                <li><button type="button" id="edit-add-kvp">Add Detail</button></li>
            </ul>
            <input class="edit-apply" type="submit" value="Apply" />
        </form>
    </div>-->
    
    <div style="display:none">
        <template id="series-template">
            <section>
                <h1 class="Name"></h1>
                <ul class="Issues">
                </ul>
            </section>
        </template>
        <template id="series-issue">
            <li>
                <input class="Have" title="I have" type="checkbox"> 
                #<span class="IssueID"></span> 
                <span class="CoverDate" data-format="[$]"></span>
                <span class="Title"></span> 
                <span class="Type"></span> 
                <span class="Collection"></span>  
                <span class="Paid"></span>  
                <span class="Where"></span>  
                <span class="When"></span>  
                <!-- <span class="Purchase"></span> <button class='edit'>edit</button> -->
            </li>
        </template>
        <template id="edit-issue">
            <form class="edit">
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="text" class="key" value="IssueID" readonly=""><input type="number" class="value"></li>
                    <li><label><input class="Have" data-property="Have" title="I have" type="checkbox"> Have</label></li>
                    <li><input type="text" class="key" value="Paid"><input type="text" class="value"></li>
                    <li><input type="text" class="key" value="Where"><input type="text" class="value"></li>
                    <li><input type="text" class="key" value="When"><input type="text" class="value"></li>
                    <li><input type="text" class="key"><input type="text" class="value"></li>
                    <li><button type="button" id="edit-add-kvp">Add Detail</button></li>
                </ul>
                <input class="edit-apply" type="submit" value="Apply">
            </form>
        </template>
    </div>
    
    <footer>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Help Center</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h5>a MazeEditing attempt</h5>
<!--        <img src="facebook-logo.png">
        <img src="twitter-logo.png">
        <img src="linkedin-logo.png"> -->
    </footer>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following line inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This `meta` tag gives the browser instructions to scale content and you should include it in all your web pages. The `content` attribute sets the width to match the viewing device and `initial-scale` sets the initial zoom of the page when loaded.

Comment: thanks, well worth the points. A bit annoyed this not the default on mobile browsers by now?